# Creating a valid heartbeat request

Tags: python, ssl, heartbleed-bug

I've been messing around with the heartbleed bug (mainly the [cloudflare challenge](https://www.cloudflarechallenge.com/heartbleed)) and creating an invalid heartbeat has been easy, I've been sending as follows:

```
### HEATBEAT ###

0x18,       # Content Type (Heartbeat)
0x03, 0x01,  # TLS version
0x00, 0x03,  # Length
# Payload
0x01,       # Type (Request)
0xff, 0xff  # Payload length
            # NO PAYLOAD

### END HEARBEAT ###
```

However, when I tried to send this valid heartbeat, the server doesn't respond.

```
### HEATBEAT ###

0x18,       # Content Type (Heartbeat)
0x03, 0x01,  # TLS version
0x00, 0x03,  # Length
# Payload
0x01,       # Type (Request)
0x00, 0x03  # Payload length
0x68, 0x61, 0x74, # Payload: hat

### END HEARBEAT ###
```

I've tried jiggling around the payload length and neither +1 or -1 work. Even lengths significantly higher than the actual length don't work. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my [full code](http://pastebin.com/6GiFc8Uk) for any interested (it's based off of [this](https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280))

EDIT: In response to @warren-dew, this also doesn't work:

```
### HEATBEAT ###

0x18,       # Content Type (Heartbeat)
0x03, 0x01,  # TLS version
0x00, 0x03,  # Length
# Payload
0x01,       # Type (Request)
0x00, 0x03  # Payload length
0x68, 0x61, 0x74, # Payload: hat
0x34, 0x90, 0xf0, 0xf3, # PADDING
0xe3, 0xb4, 0x5c, 0x9c, # PADDING
0x80, 0xff, 0x95, 0x74, # PADDING
0x9d, 0x81, 0xfa, 0xa0  # PADDING
### END HEARBEAT ###
```

EDIT: In response to @warren-dew, adjusted again but still does not work:

```
### HEATBEAT ###

0x18,       # Content Type (Heartbeat)
0x03, 0x01,  # TLS version
0x00, 0x16,  # Length <- Changed
# Payload
0x01,       # Type (Request)
0x00, 0x03  # Payload length
0x68, 0x61, 0x74, # Payload: hat
0x34, 0x90, 0xf0, 0xf3, # PADDING
0xe3, 0xb4, 0x5c, 0x9c, # PADDING
0x80, 0xff, 0x95, 0x74, # PADDING
0x9d, 0x81, 0xfa, 0xa0  # PADDING
### END HEARBEAT ###
```

Comment: you can't send this message unencrypted as it can't be sent during a handshake. You need to first handshake then send this message encrypted. Meaning this message is encapsulated in a TLSCompressed  structure which is itself encapsulated in a TLSCiphertext structure

Answer (score 2):

A legal heartbeat message has, in addition to the payload, three bytes of metadata - message type and payload length - and a minimum of 16 bytes of padding.  As a result, the message length has to exceed the payload length by at least 19 bytes, rather than merely being equal to it.  See RFC 6520 for more detail.

Comment: I added 16 bytes of random padding to the end of the request (as seen in my above edit), and the request still fails...

Comment: The message length is still the same as the payload length.  You need to adjust the message length to the correct value, which is now 22.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work... Edited to add the new message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a valid heartbeat request is only allowed after a tls session has been established. I have tested (and you can test either with s_client or your own tool perhaps using BouncyCastle) sending a valid heartbeat request after establishing a TLS session. 
I established a valid tls session and sent in an encrypted heartbeat and was able to elicit a heartbeat response using java and bouncycastle. 
I have not cleaned out the code and once I do will post it.
So empirically, it seems that even in OpenSSL versions that are broken, a valid heartbeat request right after ServerHelloDone is disallowed. That would be the reason that in the examples above, a heartbeat response is not forthcoming.